# SwiftUI or Beta-State leads to crash?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm experiencing weird behavior with SwiftUI and xCode 11 Beta 2, and I'm wondering whether it's related to wrong code or the beta-state. I have following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var persistence: Persistence

    var modal = Modal(SignupView())

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello \(persistence.userNickname)")
            Button(action: {
                self.persistence.isLoggedIn.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Swap")
            }
            }.presentation(persistence.isLoggedIn ? nil : modal)
    }
}


struct SignupView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var persistence: Persistence

    var body: some View {
        Text("Please Login")
    }

}
```

If I **comment out** the `@EnvironmentObject var persistence: Persistence` in the `SignupView`, the App works and the presentation of the modal view **works flawlessly**.

In contrast, if I keep the `@EnvironmentObject var persistence: Persistence` in the `SignupView` **uncommented** (hence as active code), the **app crashes** at startup somewhere in the `AppDelegate` without leaving any Stacktrace... `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

The Persistence Object is of type `BindableObject` and correctly added as `.environmentObject` to the `ContenView` in the `SceneDelegate`. The `isLoggedIn` Property is set to `false`

Any clue whether I'm just dealing with a Beta or real issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hmmm it looks like it's caused by a code error. If I write my ContentView as follows, it works:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var persistence: Persistence

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello \(persistence.userNickname)")
            Button(action: {
                self.persistence.isLoggedIn.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Swap")
            }
            }.presentation(persistence.isLoggedIn ? nil :
                Modal(SignupView().environmentObject(persistence))
        )
    }
}
```

I obviously have to declare the `.environmentObject` for my `SignupView` as well (analog what is done in the `SceneDelegate` for the `ContentView`)

But isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: Answering your own question is **good**. But answering your own question with something *not* definitive *and* concluding *"is there a more elegant way"*? ? How about editing your actual question for all this? Please, remember two things: (1) SO is about Q&A, period. About being a *resource*, not a *debugging tool*. (2) SwiftUi is barely in beta 2 - and while you acknowledge this in your title, your answer? Asks for a more elegant one. Please, let's help out everyone. Your answer belongs as part of your question.

Comment: @dfd adding a comment like "is there a more elegant way?" has nothing to do with not definitive - since my solution actually works and it took me almost an hour to find out -, but much rather with being humble (for what you weirdly seem to blame me)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar crash in SwiftUI, with this `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` garbage.

Converting my SwiftUI view from a `class` to a `struct` fixed it.